# Fire an event every second

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

Quick question:

I need an event that fires every second, just like the timer1_timer() event of VB6. I'm using VB9/Silverlight, creating a small sidebar gadget.

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good alternative to the DispatchTimer is the Storyboard timer:

http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/09/storyboard-versus-dispatchertimer-for-animation-and-game-loops.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use Threads and Timers:

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/27/make-a-silverlight-timer-silverlight-2.aspx